# How can I add a cumulative trend line to a histogram based on weight instead of Y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having some trouble adding a cumulative trend line to a histogram.

[image]

Looking for something like this:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
stack_structure %>%
  mutate(tonne.km = Freight_weight * Distances_.km._Main_whole.transport.chain,
         cumsum.tk = cumsum(tonne.km))  
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Distances_.km._Main_whole.transport.chain, weight = tonne.km, binwidth = 25)) +
  ylab("Tonne.km") +
  xlab("Total distance (trucks only)") +
  scale_x_continuous(label = comma,
                     breaks = extended_breaks(10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
  stat_ecdf(mapping = aes(y=cumsum.tk))
```

Best I get is that weird vertical line at 0. Have tried geom_line as well, but I can't get that to work since I am using tonne.km as Weight instead of as a Y. I also tried to create a cumsum variable for tonne.km, but to no avail...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is a sample of the data I am using (sorry for the length):

```
stack_struc <- structure(list(Distances_.km._Main_whole.transport.chain = c(4634.21949, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.969416456, 5.28602654, 
104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 104.06295, 0.662686844, 0.482527796, 
3073.29849, 393.693392, 106.313853, 5.27671504, 104.443211, 104.443211, 
104.443211, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 
104.443211, 0.580947338, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 5.64919497, 5.51916034, 104.06295, 104.06295, 
104.06295, 104.06295, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 104.06295, 7297.59359, 393.693392, 5.27671504, 
765.980058, 8681.22183, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 5.54664896, 5.51916034, 5.28602654, 104.06295, 104.06295, 
104.06295, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 393.693392, 
8755.90119, 5.27671504, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 8190.90473, 176.602334, 
176.602334, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 0, 5.51916034, 5.28602654, 104.06295, 
104.06295, 104.06295, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 0.492292035, 0.662686844, 0.482527796, 0.129123598, 
1455.41165, 393.693392, 106.313853, 5.27671504, 5.67697554, 8190.90473, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 106.313853, 5.54664896, 5.81958978, 5.51916034, 0.969416456, 
104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 104.06295, 0.492292035, 
873.837477, 106.313853, 5.27671504, 121.447109, 1060.89807, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106.313853, 0, 5.51916034, 
5.61652834, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 6.86431331, 873.837477, 104.443211, 
104.443211, 104.443211, 104.443211, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 5.67697554, 
0.377885893, 121.37723, 646.102113, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 106.313853, 0, 5.51916034, 104.06295, 
104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 104.06295, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 5.27671504, 
5.27671504, 5.27671504, 0.129123598, 0, 3073.29849, 5.27671504, 
5.67697554, 5.67697554, 176.602334, 1702.74702, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 106.313853, 
106.313853), Freight_weight = c(2.5992, 22.07984, 12.5575, 4.258488, 
2.195916, 0.050368, 1.110228, 1.56507, 0.148176, 1.06436, 1.22528, 
1.66985, 9.855, 0.458, 3.043874, 1.92968, 6.889056, 0.222507, 
0.899892, 11.23952, 0.444594, 0.279888, 0.445014, 0.084, 0.666891, 
8.141325, 0.36484, 14.347904, 10.35, 0.824632, 1.83794, 2.51552, 
0.10775, 6.27625, 3.924198, 26.00446, 0.57213, 3.269592, 2.2005, 
0.216507, 0.890028, 5.033, 8.472372, 3.664, 0.03078, 1.66888, 
1.0066, 0.251325, 1.021, 1.3203, 0.66015, 0.459038, 1.10025, 
0.3878, 0.629125, 0.08232, 0.1032, 18.93461, 16.223964, 61.831236, 
5.04772, 1.15584, 4.297224, 2.94053, 1.620034, 2.352424, 0.39216, 
0.06192, 0.00054, 2.212776, 0.20152, 0.042226, 1.374, 0.015129, 
1.08, 6.846297, 0.47492, 7.774384, 1.254804, 1.699594, 2.6406, 
3.105, 2.72578, 0.02042, 2.22507, 5.36922, 4.66506, 0.126075, 
1.901, 11.97948, 0.222297, 12.954485, 0.473884, 0.287748, 0.26406, 
0.176507, 0.15129, 0.9189, 1.4294, 0.684093, 1.37855, 0.25215, 
2.2005, 18.45615, 0.2015, 1.201365, 1.269, 0.146247, 1.7273, 
1.10025, 2.5, 1.4517, 1.847508, 3.62134, 4.31298, 0.356938, 0.00739, 
1.10025, 3.5893, 0.061565, 16.65758, 37.350948, 13.858, 45.858912, 
2.59488, 5.329615, 2.348856, 7.0984, 0.816, 2.944504, 3.978, 
0.556869, 3.40272, 0.272241, 3.30963, 10.101916, 0.216297, 2.51, 
2.448, 2.670084, 6.483234, 2.366889, 0.882535, 1.9584, 0.433014, 
1.9584, 1.509042, 2.504112, 0.325388, 7.517832, 2.51, 2.460136, 
2.02446, 0.72, 1.6279, 0.816, 1.207797, 0.00739, 0.126, 3.03669, 
11.027, 0.3672, 0.21713, 0.012348, 0.327114, 0.444594, 6.1025, 
0.502, 18.82875, 1.9584, 1.111485, 2.04, 3.67584, 3.77475, 0.5033, 
1.632, 0.101068, 1.01223, 0.444594, 1.01223, 1.229311, 0.255, 
2.5165, 1.70145, 17.80056, 14.6276, 20.474216, 0.5168, 1.110468, 
11, 4.8285, 0.1856, 1.374, 3.461472, 1.25825, 0.816, 2.4242, 
1.5099, 0.5105, 0.034306, 0.01662, 2.693118, 3.43278, 1.147164, 
2.06057, 0.554, 5.47782, 0.0876, 0.816, 7.5355, 4.084, 0.75216, 
0.48484, 0.38484, 1.07212, 6.421264, 3.6584, 0.4, 8.146956, 0.218178, 
3.03669, 1.45233, 0.6126, 4.06646, 0.6, 1.7244, 2.68464, 0.8168, 
1.25825, 14.9408, 1.58436, 0.276815, 3.3325, 0.486, 0.100765, 
3.162, 0.069706, 2.22297, 0.216297, 0.61614, 0.8802, 4.08, 2.66825, 
0.408, 6.06925, 0.90247, 26.65712, 34.923204, 10, 20.089254, 
3.663448, 11, 2.510136, 7.035, 5.56413, 0.085765, 14.07, 1.599042, 
0.01108, 1.732056, 0.25267, 20.77674, 0.52, 1.673424, 2.01, 0.628776, 
8.442, 0.408, 11.36202, 31.73702, 12.66076, 2.72862, 0.8802, 
1.021, 15.371104, 9.82752, 10.05, 6.871832, 3.287742, 0.816, 
0.48105, 2.61, 1.645, 1.1424, 0.890028, 2.7675, 0.222297, 1.407, 
5.471376, 16.884, 1.53936, 4.044759, 0.22005, 2.1216, 0.444594, 
9.485498, 3.015, 4.221, 11.958768, 0.546158, 0.0698, 0.12592, 
2.242608, 2.72862, 1.974882, 0.6126, 4.689546, 0.0831, 0.39732, 
4.3644, 0.57936, 0.45948, 1.906118, 0.216297, 11.24704, 0.60049, 
6.65994, 3.464112, 7.72476, 6.361644, 1.743753, 7.34938, 0.461276, 
1.33331, 1.9584, 0.255, 3.60882, 0.07328, 1.822514, 4.21764, 
1.8, 20.12056, 8.517976, 11.9211, 16.89975, 8.222136, 1.3736, 
10.700161, 12.946092, 3.7192, 1.160692, 0.7, 9.758727, 0.284578, 
9.1896, 1.47519, 1.62694, 0.353014, 0.20638, 0.7, 0.906555, 0.50904, 
14.441908, 1.25525, 4.32594, 7.74, 0.4857, 1.9584, 1.79774, 0.4649, 
0.6714, 1.82823, 6.2159, 1.085616, 1.568112, 0.09673, 0.25605, 
1.3947, 1.97412, 0.02276, 7.589, 1.07828, 0.569, 3.5655, 0.1431, 
0.581125, 1.25825, 5.7726, 0.816, 0.416, 22.005, 10.18757, 1.110287, 
2.62315, 12.438718, 0.4401, 1.234737, 1.250878, 3.292, 38.77152, 
1.077603, 1.828137, 0.609379, 2.673225, 2.248563, 0.169156, 1.363554, 
1.371837, 0.914815, 29.5256, 0.985068, 12.55, 5.577996, 2.042, 
0.813575, 2.811577, 0.33239, 7.487339, 17.809424, 4.737, 1.333782, 
0.334971, 2.49067, 0.648891, 0.27881, 4.5875, 1.0083, 2.2742, 
8.60643, 4.5948, 0.5467, 0.2, 4.835043, 2.31852, 5.105, 0.72726, 
0.016, 3.91714, 4.5, 2.2462, 0.656712, 1.5316, 1.085616, 1.085616, 
3.10618, 0.25165, 4.098649, 2.247628, 0.51534, 0.816, 0.72726, 
0.110946, 0.408, 0.59132, 3.4932, 4.084, 8.73026, 8.262, 4.1861, 
2.592646, 1.45936, 0.476957, 3.417666, 0.40344, 18.32, 0.816, 
1.333782, 0.377475, 0.916, 3.77475, 1.83792, 0.353014, 0.054, 
0.444594, 9.2298, 0.2042, 0.1374, 1.25825, 0.01587, 0.063339, 
0.216507, 1.62605, 0.797996, 0.378851, 36.406486, 0.162509, 5.7658, 
1.8277, 10.21, 2.530308, 1.006028, 4.309593, 5.34171, 2.09205, 
0.906555, 1.687328, 2.691577, 0.581808, 0.06714, 5.02, 0.102, 
5.02, 9.43707, 6.17563, 1.119735, 4.45014, 2.22297, 0.060516, 
2.5416, 0.15512), tonne.km = c(12045.263298408, 2347.39286402352, 
1335.0362090475, 452.736267234264, 233.456290824348, 5.354816147904, 
118.032616388484, 166.38862191471, 15.753161482128, 113.15621257908, 
130.26423780384, 177.52818743205, 1047.723021315, 48.691744674, 
323.605972986522, 205.15171585704, 732.402086892768, 23.655576489471, 
95.670985803876, 1194.91667707056, 47.266501160682, 29.755971688464, 
47.311152978942, 8.930363652, 70.899751741023, 865.535629275225, 
38.78754612852, 1525.38095671411, 1100.34837855, 87.669805227096, 
195.39848298282, 267.43462349856, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 8.21325683815363, 19.36800124256, 3.203057601, 173.668575996, 
104.74976547, 26.15362090875, 5.38752605584, 6.966846867312, 
3.483423433656, 2.42221271853152, 5.80570572276, 40.35561201, 
0.4169128607315, 0.03972168816672, 317.164404168, 7454.43083709712, 
1724.83212377329, 326.265812942989, 527.20008502892, 120.71964100224, 
448.815872946264, 16.6933168846362, 9.19689339196836, 13.354653507709, 
2.2262827277664, 0.3515183254368, 0.05639933394, 1.28550632679029, 
21.42436765656, 4.489208756778, 146.075234022, 1.608422282037, 
114.81896124, 727.856212852341, 50.49057506676, 826.524717741552, 
133.403047999812, 180.690386675682, 280.7323602318, 330.104513565, 
289.78817423034, 2.17092887826, 236.55576489471, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1962.14441804595, 21.4222413795, 
127.721742009345, 7.16882841693, 0.80716064224398, 179.747933535, 
114.4952607375, 260.157375, 151.068184515, 9.74877325012032, 
19.1087792429536, 22.7583664332192, 1.88346011294752, 0.0389949241456, 
5.80570572276, 373.513146435, 449.27634936835, 6557.97917271136, 
197.090309069858, 10614.951643764, 398111.387954449, 275.87169087264, 
566.611905656595, 249.715931502168, 754.6582541352, 86.752104048, 
313.041565413912, 422.916507234, 59.202889006257, 361.75627388016, 
28.942989654573, 351.85951730439, 1073.97361264235, 22.995367462341, 
266.84777103, 260.256312144, 283.866917873652, 689.257586440602, 
251.633089213317, 93.825696257355, 208.2050497152, 46.035386742942, 
208.2050497152, 160.432069358826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104.4364666056, 10.808723609856, 
5.8753392088119, 212.288418, 382.518754128, 392.8116205125, 2.655770679632, 
8.61159894528, 0.53330703566272, 5.3412492649392, 2.34599584649376, 
5.3412492649392, 6.48672384253744, 1.3455623352, 13.27885339816, 
8.978066804808, 7007.96284589952, 128077.820246844, 108.036603499409, 
2.933860959072, 6.30409967395272, 90099.95203, 852.724369719, 
32.7773931904, 146.075234022, 368.002425371616, 133.76940553725, 
86.752104048, 257.7260424426, 160.5232866447, 54.2732219565, 
3.647203041018, 1.76693623686, 286.315751163654, 364.95206830134, 
121.959424862892, 219.06713607621, 58.897874562, 582.36815024046, 
9.3130935228, 86.752104048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 133.76940553725, 1588.4140149024, 168.43941613908, 
0, 18.39260183305, 2.56900889844, 10.48590315675, 329.0470479, 
7.2538119927, 11.7299792324688, 1.14133763300688, 3.2511952047456, 
4.644564578208, 21.5289973632, 1.31355822238875, 0.270376232352, 
2.928581825873, 0.11653017348706, 38797.083003448, 13749.034642268, 
1063.13853, 106.00526872418, 20.7973046880619, 90099.95203, 266.862229714008, 
747.917955855, 591.54409889289, 9.118007602545, 1495.83591171, 
170.000316128826, 1.17795749124, 184.141546971768, 26.86232123751, 
2208.85528217922, 55.28320356, 177.908153142672, 213.69084453, 
66.847599233928, 897.501547026, 43.376052024, 1207.94012406306, 
3374.08487893806, 1346.01417750828, 290.09010557286, 93.5774534106, 
108.546443913, 1634.16129110371, 1044.80151663456, 1068.45422265, 
730.570937088696, 349.532519689926, 86.752104048, 51.14227898565, 
277.47915633, 174.886288185, 121.4529456672, 94.622305957884, 
294.2235881775, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.995367462341, 62.3833827190784, 
3.4946054669922, 36.7572767147796, 3.35816717822707, 803.861313642, 
662.0114414898, 181.46008125135, 764.798163471, 48.0017413242, 
138.7481718645, 10.333918734336, 1.3455623352, 19.0427147706528, 
0.3866776781312, 189.6561832563, 2.0763105784974, 1572.9074586, 
2139.09425811768, 44.946932069559, 1447.7831310999, 17928.9121584825, 
874.126958050008, 146.0327084808, 1137.57534363033, 1376.34892181248, 
395.4024820776, 123.397638666276, 74.4196971, 1037.48786774513, 
30.254583659034, 976.9817835288, 156.83313280707, 172.96625999982, 
37.530278502942, 21.94105298214, 74.4196971, 96.379355006415, 
54.11800373112, 1535.37488415152, 133.45046397825, 459.90734924682, 
822.86922222, 51.6366384021, 208.2050497152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 133.76940553725, 0, 4.50363483744, 
2.33647578944, 2289.90521475, 1060.1485875315, 115.53974056665, 
272.9727272925, 1294.4096892981, 2.322282289104, 6.51535529834448, 
6.60052675580512, 22.59731941652, 33880.007216255, 112.548317503233, 
190.936498427907, 63.645499475969, 279.200202725475, 12.765037151149, 
0.96029447444424, 7.74086270546916, 0.518397849795441, 111.03771066245, 
19076.5525475928, 104.726374547004, 1334.23885515, 593.018246778588, 
217.092887826, 86.494292954475, 298.909583876181, 35.33766159867, 
796.007857807167, 1893.38848515067, 503.608721661, 141.799503482046, 
35.612057653263, 264.79272425151, 68.986102387023, 29.64136535493, 
487.7148006375, 107.1962579799, 241.7789644926, 914.98273387479, 
488.4908917644, 58.1217834351, 21.2627706, 514.032050750679, 
246.49079445756, 542.732219565, 77.31781273278, 1.701021648, 
416.44624614042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42.89126085432, 0, 4.50363483744, 
138.7972895769, 39.28116205125, 95.3216622, 392.8116205125, 191.259377064, 
36.7356782313, 0.28494261216, 2.34599584649376, 48.703024476192, 
1.077505211168, 0.725020646496, 6.63942669908, 0.0837414676848, 
0.33422185391856, 1.14244574316528, 0.2099614265279, 0, 1164.32220623499, 
192.106652229749, 0.92255961802986, 32.732305568532, 322.7760858518, 
17385.0470742, 269.006792756724, 106.954712905884, 458.169436691829, 
567.89777170863, 222.41389616865, 96.379355006415, 179.386340954784, 
286.151921516181, 61.854250186224, 7.13791209042, 533.69554206, 
10.844013006, 533.69554206, 1003.29127273071, 656.55502000239, 
119.043342188955, 473.11152978942, 236.33250580341, 6.433689128148, 
270.2072887848, 16.49140487736)), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Is it possible that you share slightly more data? When I reproduce your code, the histogram looks awful.

Comment: Hi Quinten. Im afraid not, however, I can try to make some sample data. Will get on it later - thanks!

Comment: Hi again, I resubmitted the question with some sample data. If you can help, I would appreciate it highly! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385371/how-can-one-add-a-cumulative-trend-line-based-on-weight-to-a-histogram-in-r