# How can one add a cumulative trend line based on weight to a histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

Having some serious trouble adding a cumulative trend line to my histogram below. The key difference from all the examples I can find is that the x-axis should be bins of distance, **but the y-axis the sum of tonne.km per bin**. I am using weight for this. The cumulative density curve should include the weight = tonne.km.

Some randomly generated data for this.

```
distance<-rnorm(1000000, mean = 1000, sd = 500)
tonne.km<-rnorm(1000000, mean = 25000, sd = 500)
dist.tk.test <- structure(tibble(distance, tonne.km))
```

My code:

```
dist.tk.test %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = distance, y=..density.., weight = tonne.km), bins = 50) +
  stat_bin(aes(x = distance, y=cumsum(..density..)),geom="line",color="red") + 
  scale_x_continuous(label = comma,
                     breaks = extended_breaks(10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x)x*1,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., labels = scales::percent, name = "Cumulative Share (%)"))
```

This is the visual outcome:

[image]

I would like the line to follow the second y-axis, and the first y-axis to have the sum of tonne.km per bin instead of the current density.

Is this possible using weight=tonne.km? Or do I need to use a completely different graph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the histogram and line be scaled?

Comment: Hi Quinten! Yes, definitely. And tonne.km on 1st y-axis, share in % on 2nd y-axis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_histogram` does not have a `weight` aesthetic so I do not understand how do you want to do with `tonne.km`. But if you want to superimpose the CDF to the histogram, here is a way.

First realize that a density such as the empirical histogram density and a ECDF are many times on different scales, specially if the distribution is continuous and the sample is large. Then, the main trick is to scale the ECDF by the maximum density y value.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

distance <- rnorm(1000000, mean = 1000, sd = 500)
tonne.km <- rnorm(1000000, mean = 25000, sd = 500)
dist.tk.test <- data.frame(distance, tonne.km)

bins <- 50L
x_breaks <- 10L

max_y <- max(density(dist.tk.test$distance)$y)

ggplot(dist.tk.test) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(x = distance, y = ..density..), bins = bins
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      x = sort(distance),
      y = max_y * seq_along(distance)/length(distance)
    ),
    color = "red"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(label = comma,
                     breaks = extended_breaks(x_breaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Density",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x / max_y , 
                        labels = scales::percent, 
                        name = "Cumulative Share (%)")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

Following the comment below, here is another solution.
The total `tonne.km` by bins of `distance` is computed first.
In order to do this, the distances must be binned. I use `findInterval` to bin them and then sum the `tonne.km` per bin (variable `breaks`) with `aggregate`. This is the data.frame used in the plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(2022)
distance <- rnorm(1000000, mean = 1000, sd = 500)
tonne.km <- rnorm(1000000, mean = 25000, sd = 500)
dist.tk.test <- data.frame(distance, tonne.km)

breaks <- range(dist.tk.test$distance)
breaks <- round(breaks/100)*100
breaks <- seq(breaks[1], breaks[2], by = 50)
bins <- findInterval(dist.tk.test$distance, breaks)
breaks <- breaks[bins]

new_df <- aggregate(tonne.km ~ breaks, dist.tk.test, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
y_max <- max(new_df$tonne.km, na.rm = TRUE)

x_axis_breaks <- 10L

ggplot(new_df, aes(breaks, tonne.km)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 100) +
  geom_line(
    aes(
      y = y_max * cumsum(tonne.km)/sum(tonne.km)
    ),
    color = "red"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Distance",
    label = comma,
    breaks = extended_breaks(x_axis_breaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Tonne/Km",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .x/y_max, 
                        labels = scales::percent, 
                        name = "Cumulative Share (%)")
  )
#> Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Rui, thanks for that! However, the issue is that your graph above does not take into account the sum of tonne.km per bin. 

I basically want to have a graph distance sequences on the x-axis, e.g. 0-50 km, 50-100 km. 

Then, on 1st y-axis, the sum of tonne.km for all trips that fall into that specific bin, e..g 0-50 km. This might be in the number of 100 of thousands of tonne.km. 

I thought I could do that with the weight = tonne.km in ggplot, but I guess not?

Comment: @DavidFærgeman Done, see the edit.

Comment: Awesome, Rui! Will test with my data. Thanks a ton.